# How do I make the second element of a paragraph indent

Tags: html, css

I have this imagery attached, the (01) is sitting as a fixed element, while the others need (Understanding your expectation) to indent appropriately under each other.[image: What needs to be fixed]

Find attached my css code

```
<div class="col-md-3 verticalLine "><h2><span class="numberCircle">01</span><span><a href="#">Understanding your Expectations</a></span></h2>
<p>We need to fully understand what you want to achieve so we consider all possible solutions.</p>

</div>
```

I basically want the Understanding your expectations to be indented away from the 01 and also the broken word(s) to be under the first word in the sentence.

Thanks

--CSS---

```
.sectors-a div h2 {
    color: #5FD0FF;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: normal;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.sectors-a div h2 span a {
color: #5FD0FF;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
  font-family: Pathway Gothic, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  /* height: 28px; */
/*
  text-indent: 100px;
  padding-left: 10px;
*/
padding-left:10px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
} 
.sectors-a div h2 span a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.sectors-a div h2  span.numberCircle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc); /* remove if you don't care about IE8 */

    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 8px;

    background: #5FD0FF;
    border: 2px solid #5FD0FF;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
   font-weight: 900;
   font-family: Pathway Gothic, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
}
.verticalLine {
    border-right: 1px solid #727272;
}

.sectors-a {
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding-top: 40px;
     margin-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: url('../img/tabsBtmBg.png') repeat;
}
.ie .sectors div h2 a {
 font-family: Exo2-ExtraBoldItalic,Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
}
.sectors div a {

    margin-left: 0;
    line-height: 21px;
    font-size: 14px;
/*    font-family: Pathway Gothic IE, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;*/
}
```

Comment: Pretty much none of the css you've attached is relevant to the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply a `display: table;` to the `<h2>` that wraps both span tags and apply `display:table-cell; padding-left: 15px;` to `<span class="numberCircle">01</span>` to give it space between the number and title.

Here is the CSS snippet:

```
.col-md-3 {
    width:200px;
    position:relative;
}
.col-md-3 h2 {
    display: table;
}
.numberCircle {
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Le8xvo68/

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the number circle from the document flow with a `position:absolute` then set a `display:inline-block` and a `padding` on the heading.

```
.col-md-3 {
    width:200px; // The width of your column's
    position:relative;
}
.numberCircle {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
h2 a {
     padding-left:40px; // The space for your numberCircle
     display:inline-block;
}
```

[Here's a jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hzen63xn/1/)